# Pixel Inspector in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I use pixel inspector in Arcgis  to find cell values. this is very helpful tool in arcgis. I wanted to know if there is such a tool in Qgis which can help me to find the cell values(Except the identify tool).

Answer (score 7):

You could try using the Value Tool which can be downloaded from the plugins menu in QGIS.